# (openGL) How to display difference between two render passes to see how well they approximate each other

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a program that displays a color surface. Then through some method (which is the focus of my thesis but unimportant here) I closely recreate the color surface. So this gives me two copies of the color surface and I want to find the 'difference' between the two outputs, to see how closely they resemble each other. So loosely speaking I want to render something like

```
abs(render_1 - render_2)
```

Because of the complicated structure of both color surfaces I can not directly calculate the difference before rendering. Is there some way that I can use GLSL shaders to do this? I was hoping that it is possible to first render one surface, then in the second render pass use a shader that queries the color already present at the render location, but I do not think this is possible. Any thought on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render each version into its own texture using a FBO, then in a third pass you can evaluate the difference between the values in the rendered pictures (using a shader).

Comment: Ah, nice idea. Thanks, I will give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You can render first surface to frame buffer and then query value of pixel from this texture at secord render pass. Since color is 4d vector you can calculate distance between 1-st pixel fetched from texture and 2-nd pixel calculated in shader. Since difference will have been found you can calculate and visualize SNR.